# Is Task.Run better or works than Func<Task>()?

Tags: c#, async-await

In my scenario, I want to make calls to two services at the same time. The below code simulates this:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    int foo = 0;
    int bar = 0;

    await Task.WhenAll(
            Task.Run(async () => foo = await FooAsync()),
            Task.Run(async () => bar = await BarAsync()));

    Console.WriteLine(foo + bar);
}
```

While this works, should I be concerned about the number of threads involved? I've been reading about `Task.Run` [here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html) and it raises some interesting concerns about scalability.

Does this version have any advantages over the `Task.Run` approach? My first concern is correctness / scalability. Secondly, I would like to maintain readable (e.g. I think the first approach is a bit more expressive)

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    int foo = 0;
    int bar = 0;

    Func<Task> fooTask = async () => foo = await FooAsync();
    Func<Task> barTask = async () => bar = await BarAsync();

    await Task.WhenAll(
            fooTask(),
            barTask());

    Console.WriteLine(foo + bar);
}
```

For completeness:

```
private async static Task<int> FooAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
    return 1;
}

private async static Task<int> BarAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    return 3;
}
```

Comment: You can just do `fooTask = FooAsync(); barTask = BarAsync();` and remove those (likely unnecessary) wrappers.

Comment: @Evk I think the wrapper is necessary because he still wants to assign the return values to variables `foo` and `bar`. With your suggestion he still needs to read into the results of both tasks to assign the return values of the methods.

Comment: [There Is No Thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html). The number of threads that are doing any non-trivial work in your example is zero. And by non-trivial let's say more than 1 μsec of work or so.

Comment: @AndrewH but they are still available, from `fooTask.Result` and `barTask.Result`. I mean you can hardly call such wrapper "necessary". It just bothers thread pool for no reason.

Comment: That I can agree with @Evk

Comment: SO is a wrong place to discuss code writing style. As @TheodorZoulias pointed out difference in cost of is unlikely to be significant enough to overcome style preference. I personally find using `Task.Run` to start another asynchronous operation <censored> <censored> on par with mixing Parallel/async/Task/ContinueWith in single statement. But it is my personal opinion because I'm not able to explain how such code behaves - as long as you/your team understand what is happening there should be no problem doing so. (avoid going 10+levels of nested `Task.Run` doing nothing so :) )

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK `Task.Run` uses the same `TaskScheduler` as the one used to run `async Task Main`. So i think there is no difference in these approaches. Honestly i'd do it even simpler:

```cs
Task<int> fooTask = FooAsync();
Task<int> barTask = BarAsync();

await Task.WhenAll(
        fooTask,
        barTask
);

Console.WriteLine(fooTask.Result + barTask.Result);
```

Comment: Side note: suggested code is not "simpler" but just different... In your example `fooTask` is hot (running) task unlike in OP case where task will be started (possibly multiple times for retry) later.